# How to extract substring from column

Tags: python

I have a table where in one of the columns the data  is a string that looks like this:

```
[{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5001602182558444}, {'label': 0, 'prob': 0.49983978174415555}]
```

I want to extract just the number from label :1.
So it would look like this:

```
0.5001602182558444
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it with the standard methods since it has so many symbols which mess with the syntax.

Comment: list[0]['prob´] would get the prob number for the first list index in the column.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator with `next`:

```
next((x['prob'] for x in lst if x['label'] == 1), None)
```

---

```
0.5001602182558444
```

Notice I add a `None` in case for no matches, if you're sure there would be matches you can strip that `None`:

```
next((x['prob'] for x in lst if x['label'] == 1))
```

Comment: @mozway Yeah! It doesn't need to create a list then get the first value. Instead it uses a generator :)

Comment: I'm getting this error:  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use `pandas`, create a dataframe and look it up:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5001602182558444}, {'label': 0, 'prob': 0.49983978174415555}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.loc[df["label"]==1, "prob"].values[0]
# 0.5001602182558444
```